# Angular HTTP Request From File From GitHub

Tags: javascript, angular, api, github

In a Git repository I have a Json file.  I want to request it so I can parse it into a data object in my Angular App.

When I use the Git V3 API to retrieve content of the file I get this:

```
{
"name": "file.json",
"path": "path/to/file.json",
"sha": "e54635a380b571b785e802819a3aeeaa569891d9",
"size": 5571,
"url": "https://github.foo.com/api/v3/repos/MyOrigin/the-repo/contents/path/to/file.json?ref=master",
"html_url": "https://github.foo.com/MyOrigin/the-repo/blob/master/path/to/file.json",
"git_url": "https://github.foo.com/api/v3/repos/MyOrigin/the-repo/git/blobs/14524524524352345",
"download_url": "https://github.foo.com/raw/MyOrigin/the-repo/master/path/to/file.json",
"type": "file",
"_links": {
  "self": "https://github.foo.com/api/v3/repos/MyOrigin/the-repo/contents/path/to/file.json?ref=master",
  "git": "https://github.foo.com/api/v3/repos/MyOrigin/the-repo/git/blobs/24352435234523452345",
  "html": "https://github.foo.com/MyOrigin/the-repo/blob/master/path/to/file.json"
}
},
```

The above I retrieved using this script:

```
    getContent(team: string): Observable<Content> {
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    this.Url += '/' + team + '.json';
    return this._http.get(this.Url, options)
        .map((response: Response) => {
            const data = response.json();
            return {
                name: data.name,
                git_url: data.git_url,
                html_url: data.html_url,
                download_url: data.download_url,
                type: data.type,
            } as Content
        })
        .catch(e => {
            if (e.status === 401) {
                return Observable.throw('Unauthorized');
            }
            if (e.status === 404) {
                return Observable.throw('Not found.');
            }
        });
}
```

From the above response are a few URLs about the file. `download_url` I believe is the Raw file I want to request. But, the Typescript below, I try using is something like this:

```
getTheFile(download_url: string): Observable<MyFile> {
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this._http.get(download_url)
        .map((response: Response) => {
            console.log(response.text());
            return null;
        })
        .catch(e => {
            if (e.status === 401) {
                return Observable.throw('Unauthorized');
            }
            if (e.status === 404) {
                return Observable.throw('Not found.');
            }
        });
}
```

... and it fails.  How can I retrieve the actual file, and parse it to an object?

Comment: You could have a look at see how rawgit.com does it maybe... [readme of one of my repo's](https://rawgit.com/jorgt/perlin-landscape/master/README.md) in raw format.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: When using the download_url I get No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.  When using git_url, the result is base64 encoded.  Not sure how to decode on client.

Comment: @Jorg Pretty sure they have a middleware service.  Would like to not have to write a middleware as that adds one more thing to manage.